# Currency Market Question

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar

I am moving to Europe in March to start a 3 yr university course.  I will take 35,000 Australia dollars with me.  I am trying to decide how to deal with the exchange rate and would like some help.  I believe that the Australian dollar will lose more of its value before March.  Does it seem like a reasonable course then to transfer my money into USD (since I believe its value will increase) and then into Euros closer to date in March?  Alternatively is it better to just to transfer all of my money to Euros right away?

Comment: You could could buy some XDA puts to hedge. AUD/USD is a bit beat up right now as well but if you're looking for something stable, a move to USD might be good in the short run and hope that EUR/USD floats under 1.15.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to predict the future currency fluctuations that can't be predicted.

If you know for sure you are moving, convert it directly into Euros in near future rather than take a complicated route.